# How to use require() in a variable

Tags: php, require

I'm working on a JSON parser for a school project, and I have a JSON data file stored outside of my root folder (`/var/www/html/` while JSON in stored in `/var/data/`). I need to read the contents of the JSON file and use the contents. I wrote the following piece of code:

```
// $json = file_get_contents("my_data_file.json");
$json = require "/var/data/my_data_file.json";

    $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
            echo "$key:\n";
        } else {
            echo "$key => $val\n";
        }
    }
```

If I use the first `$json = file_get_contents("my_data_file.json");` it works without any problems, but since the file is outside the root folder I used `require()` to get the file. This is where I get in trouble, as using `require()` just outputs everything in that file instead of  loading the data into the variable. Is there a way of using for example `require()` or a similar call to get data out of my root folder and into a variable?

Comment: Why do you need require rather than file_get_contents??

Comment: If I use ``file_get_contents()`` for a file outside of my root folder is does not work anymore, otherwise I would rather use that @AndreySScherbakov

Comment: You cannot store the contents in a variable with just `$var = require()`... you could use require in a separate file then get the contents from that other PHP file...

Comment: I you're running from a webserver then the webserver user needs permission to `/var/data/` in order to `file_get_contents`

Comment: How would that work @Samuel? Do I just create a file with ``<?php require("/var/data/my_data_file.json"); ?>`` and use ``file_get_contents()`` for that entire file?

Comment: Just saw your answer!

Comment: If all else fails and you have to require then:  `ob_start(); require("/var/data/my_data_file.json"); $json = ob_get_clean();`

Comment: Read about [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php). It reads the file as PHP source code.

Comment: You said ”If I use the first $json = file_get_contents("my_data_file.json"); it works without any problems" then keep using file_get_contents.  I don't see what is the problem exactly.

Comment: require is normally use to include an other PHP script inside the current calling script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do that. `require` will return `bool` value if `false` and the content if true.

A possible solution is to have two separate file:

> get_content.php

```
<?php
// set header to plain text so code will return as just text
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
// require the file
require 'someJsonFile.json'; 
?>
```

> index.php

```
<?php
$json = file_get_content(get_content.php);
// ...
```

I hope this helps!

There's also another [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041313/php-store-require-once-inside-variable-and-execute-it-later#26041540), for more information on this.

Comment: I will try this and let you know! Thanks :)